# How to Normalize a Power Spectral density?

Tags: power-spectral-density

I have a spectroscopy data representing Periodogram of 1024 pts (Periodogram estimate a theoretical PSD), however it is not normalized. How do we normalize the PSD ? The normalization I am looking satisfies :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2N-1}\bar{P}(k) = 1$$

Comment: well, there you've got your formula. You integrate over your actual PSD, get some value $c$ that's not necessarily 1, and then you multiply your PSD by the inverse of that value.

Comment: Shouldn't the c value be the sum of the P array values ?

Comment: Well, you drew an integral, so there's no "array" but an integrateable function, following your notation.

Comment: Well, I am working with data (1024 pnts), I was just mentioning the theoretical framework of a normalized PSD.  In this case probably more like the one I just edited

Comment: yeah, well, then replace the word "integrate" with "sum" in my first comment :)